# Migrate SBS 2008 with Exchange 2007 to new hardware

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-sbs-2008

We have run out of hard disk space on our existing Small Business Server 2008 and simply wish to upgrade both of the hard drives (currently raid 1) - without too much hassle.

My main concern is how to copy across the embedded version of Microsoft Exchange 2007.

Is there a simple way to copy all the data across and upgrade?

Or is it best to backup and do a clean install? - The difficulty is that it's the same server, so we can't replicate mailboxes for exchange.

Any hints or tips welcomed!?

Comment: Does your RAID controller support online expansion of the arrays? If it does, there ways of doing this without formatting or re-installing anything.

Answer (score 0):

If @MarkHenderson's suggestion is not feasible then imaging the server onto separate hardware (NAS, ext HD, etc) would be the way to go.  This can be done w/ the built in MS Backup or a 3rd party app: Shadow Protect, Acronis, etc.  It should be fairly safe as you have both the original drives and the backup.  The generic process would be:
Image the server onto different hardware.
Label & document the slot location of the drives. Remove drives, store safely.
Insert the new HD's.
Boot from CD, restore backup image.